# Exclude several shipping classes from a fee based on cart items dimensions in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been getting great help here during the year, regarding a woocommerce issue where I needed an automatic fee added based on total cart height in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54871678/add-a-fee-based-on-cart-items-height-in-woocommerce/54871889#54871889) and then later updated with width in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957783/add-a-fee-based-on-cart-items-dimensions-in-woocommerce).

Now my only issue is that I need to exclude some shipping classes from the function, as they are shipped differently and don't need a Bulky fee added.

I've been playing around with the answer to "[Add a fee based on cart items dimensions in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57958255/11102947)", trying to add a class variable to it:

`// Initializing variables
    $total_height    = 0;
    $class           = 1390,1392,1389;
    $apply_fee       = false;`

But it instantly breaks the website. I've been searching on stackoverflow.com and Google for a way to do this but no luck, and I'm still not qualified enough for that type of advanced editing of code.

Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a list of ids like that with just commas between them. To fix this put the ids in an array. Within the foreach loop, check the shipping class id of the product, and if it's in the array exclude it.

```
    $exclClasses = array(1390,1392,1389);

    // Checking item with
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_width() > $width_threshold ) {
        $apply_fee = true;
    }

    // make sure product isn't in excluded shipping classes
    if (in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id(), $exclClasses)) 
    {
        $apply_fee = false;
    }
```

or to use 1 statement instead of 2

```
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_width() > $width_threshold && !in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id(), $exclClasses)) {
        $apply_fee = true;
    }
```