# Woocommerce - add surcharge in cart based on weight only to some categories (or to all cart except some categories)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

A friends ask me to add an extra fee on cart based on weight and only for specific categories (or excluding some categories, it doesn't matters).

The topic is, for summer, he wants to add ice into the packages to keep the products cold (ex. milk, cheese, etc).

He sells also gadgets and guided visits to his factory, etc so he doesn't want to apply the extra fee to those products.

Based on "[Add custom fee based on total weight in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369380/add-custom-fee-based-on-total-weight-in-woocommerce/48370019#48370019)" answer, my code version below, apply an extra fee to the whole cart, excluding the visit-product from this fee because the weight of the visit is obviously 0.

But I am not an expert with code and I don't know how to insert an array to include categories like 'milk' and 'cheese' (or viceversa to exclude 'visits' and 'gadgets').

In addiction, my code increase the fee by steps of 3kg (due to sizing of the packets by DHL/UPS/GLS etc)

```
/* Extra Fee based on weight */

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'shipping_weight_fee', 30, 1 );
function shipping_weight_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Convert in grams
    $cart_weight = $cart->get_cart_contents_weight() * 1000;
    $fee = 0.00; // initial fee 


    // if cart is > 0 add €1,20 to initial fee by steps of 3000g
    if( $cart_weight > 0 ){
        for( $i = 0; $i < $cart_weight; $i += 3000 ){
            $fee += 1.20;
        }
    }    

    // add the fee / doesn't show extra fee if it's 0
    if ( !empty( $fee )) {
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Extra for ice' ), $fee, false );
        }
}
```

Last question is: why the $i variable could be 0...1...1000000 without any change in the results? the code seems working exactly the same...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is based on:

- Predefined categories
- Based on product weight (of products belonging to the predefined categories)
- Fee increases by steps

(comment with explanation added in the code)

```php
function shipping_weight_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    /* SETTINGS */

    // Specific categories
    $specific_categories = array( 'categorie-1', 'categorie-2' );

    // Initial fee
    $fee = 1.20;

    // Steps of kg
    $steps_of_kg = 3;

    /* END SETTINGS */

    // Set variable
    $total_weight = 0;

    // Loop though each cart item
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Get weight
        $product_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();

        // NOT empty & has certain category     
        if ( ! empty( $product_weight ) && has_term( $specific_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            // Quantity
            $product_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

            // Add to total
            $total_weight += $product_weight * $product_quantity;
        }
    }

    if ( $total_weight > 0 ) {          
        $increase_by_steps = ceil( $total_weight / $steps_of_kg );

        // Add fee
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'Extra for ice' ), $fee * $increase_by_steps, false );      
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'shipping_weight_fee', 10, 1 );
```