# Weight based progressive discount displays remaining weight to get a better discount message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, message, discount

I'm using [Apply a progressive discount based onWoocommerce cart total weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63304091/apply-a-progressive-discount-based-onwoocommerce-cart-total-weight/63306059#63306059) answer code *(to my previous question)* to add volume discount based on total cart weight.

The code is perfect, but I would like to show a banner above the cart page (only cart) like the 'Added to Cart' message, which shows a message and the amount customers have to order more for the next discount rule.

Example message: "If you order for € 10,- extra you will receive a 10% discount"

I tried to find the right code for the message box, but couldn't find the right one. I can only find `wc_add_to_cart_message_html`, but I'm pretty sure this one is not the right one.

Sorry for all those questions, but I'm very new with PHP and would like to learn.
Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

You will have to replace all your related code by the following that will make a discount based on cart weight, displaying a custom message displaying the remaining weight to get a better percentage discount (percentage displayed).

> **For the message:** As it's a weight based discount, it's not possible to display a remaining cost. Instead you can display the remaining weight required to get a better discount.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'shipping_weight_discount', 30, 1 );
function shipping_weight_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $cart_weight   = $cart->get_cart_contents_weight();
    $cart_subtotal = $cart->get_subtotal(); // Or $cart->subtotal;
    $percentage    = 0;

    if ( $cart_weight >= 10 && $cart_weight < 30 ) 
    {
        $percentage       = 5;
        $remaining_weight = 30 - $cart_weight;
        $next_percent     = 7.5;
    } 
    elseif ( $cart_weight >= 30 && $cart_weight < 70 ) 
    {
        $percentage       = 7.5;
        $remaining_weight = 70 - $cart_weight;
        $next_percent     = 10;
    } 
    elseif ( $cart_weight >= 70 && $cart_weight < 130 ) 
    {
        $percentage       = 10;
        $remaining_weight = 130 - $cart_weight;
        $next_percent     = 12.5;
    } 
    elseif ( $cart_weight >= 130 && $cart_weight < 200 ) {
        $percentage       = 12.5;
        $remaining_weight = 200 - $cart_weight;
        $next_percent = 15;
    } 
    elseif ( $cart_weight >= 200 ) 
    {
        $percentage       = 15;
        $next_percent     = false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $next_percent = 5;
        $remaining_weight = 10 - $cart_weight;
    }

    // Apply a calculated discount based on weight
    if( $percentage > 0 ) {
        $discount = $cart_subtotal * $percentage / 100;
        $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __( 'Weight %s discount', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage.'%'), -$discount );
    }

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Display a custom message
    if ( is_cart() && $next_percent ) { 
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( 
            __("If you order for %s extra, you will receive a %s discount.", "woocommerce"), 
            wc_format_weight($remaining_weight), $next_percent.'%'
        ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Screenshot of the message displayed in cart:

[image]

Comment: I understand that it should be in weight in stead of amount. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I changed the steps to `[10, 5], [30, 7.5], [70, 10], [130, 12.5], [200, 15]` and discovered a small bug in the code.  If I add 1kg to the cart, the message says that I have to order for 9kg more to get a 5% discount. That is not correct. It should be 10kg (discount have to apply from 10, not when 10kg is reached). And when I add 9kg extra's to the cart it applies the 5% discount and the message says that I have to order for 20kg more to get a 7,5% discount. When I do that the correct message appears (order for 40kg more to get 7,5%) but I still have the 5% discount instead of the 7,5%.

Comment: I tried to change this in the stept by change every weight with plus one. But that did not gave me to solution. I think it's in `$steps[0][0] && $cart_weight <= $steps[1][0]`, but I do not understand these values. So sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: Thanks for you reaction. I understand your explanation. But then it doesn't apply the discount correctly. See this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/5uzmAfm) please. You can see here that I have to order 1kg more for 5% discount. But when I do that the 5% discount stays. Only the message change to the new variable. Hope you understand my problem. It looks like there's a difference from 1 between the message and the discount calculation.

Comment: Your my hero, thank you. This works perfect indeed! I only noticed that the discount percentage is not shown properly in the message, but only %, while the code is perfect in my opinion?